# I want to select that persons who do not earn commission

Tags: oracle

```
SQL> select last_name, job_id, salary, commission_pct from employees;

LAST_NAME                 JOB_ID         SALARY COMMISSION_PCT                                                                                                                                          
------------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------                                                                                                                                          
King                      AD_PRES         24000                                                                                                                                                         
Kochhar                   AD_VP           17000                                                                                                                                                         
De Haan                   AD_VP           17000                                                                                                                                                         
Hunold                    IT_PROG          9000                                                                                                                                                         
Ernst                     IT_PROG          6000                                                                                                                                                         
Austin                    IT_PROG          4800                                                                                                                                                         
Pataballa                 IT_PROG          4800                                                                                                                                                         
Lorentz                   IT_PROG          4200                                                                                                                                                         
Greenberg                 FI_MGR          12008                                                                                                                                                         
Faviet                    FI_ACCOUNT       9000                                                                                                                                                         
Chen                      FI_ACCOUNT       8200                                                                                                                                                         
Sciarra                   FI_ACCOUNT       7700                                                                                                                                                         
Urman                     FI_ACCOUNT       7800                                                                                                                                                         
Popp                      FI_ACCOUNT       6900                                                                                                                                                         
Raphaely                  PU_MAN          11000                                                                                                                                                         
Khoo                      PU_CLERK         3100                                                                                                                                                         
Baida                     PU_CLERK         2900                                                                                                                                                         
Tobias                    PU_CLERK         2800                                                                                                                                                         
Himuro                    PU_CLERK         2600                                                                                                                                                         
Colmenares                PU_CLERK         2500                                                                                                                                                         
Weiss                     ST_MAN           8000                                                                                                                                                         
Fripp                     ST_MAN           8200                                                                                                                                                         
Kaufling                  ST_MAN           7900                                                                                                                                                         
Vollman                   ST_MAN           6500                                                                                                                                                         
Mourgos                   ST_MAN           5800                                                                                                                                                         
Nayer                     ST_CLERK         3200                                                                                                                                                         
Mikkilineni               ST_CLERK         2700                                                                                                                                                         
Landry                    ST_CLERK         2400                                                                                                                                                         
Markle                    ST_CLERK         2200                                                                                                                                                         
Bissot                    ST_CLERK         3300                                                                                                                                                         
Atkinson                  ST_CLERK         2800                                                                                                                                                         
Marlow                    ST_CLERK         2500                                                                                                                                                         
Olson                     ST_CLERK         2100                                                                                                                                                         
Mallin                    ST_CLERK         3300                                                                                                                                                         
Rogers                    ST_CLERK         2900                                                                                                                                                         
Gee                       ST_CLERK         2400                                                                                                                                                         
Philtanker                ST_CLERK         2200                                                                                                                                                         
Ladwig                    ST_CLERK         3600                                                                                                                                                         
Stiles                    ST_CLERK         3200                                                                                                                                                         
Seo                       ST_CLERK         2700                                                                                                                                                         
Patel                     ST_CLERK         2500                                                                                                                                                         
Rajs                      ST_CLERK         3500                                                                                                                                                         
Davies                    ST_CLERK         3100                                                                                                                                                         
Matos                     ST_CLERK         2600                                                                                                                                                         
Vargas                    ST_CLERK         2500                                                                                                                                                         
Russell                   SA_MAN          14000             .4                                                                                                                                          
Partners                  SA_MAN          13500             .3                                                                                                                                          
Errazuriz                 SA_MAN          12000             .3                                                                                                                                          
Cambrault                 SA_MAN          11000             .3                                                                                                                                          
Zlotkey                   SA_MAN          10500             .2                                                                                                                                          
Tucker                    SA_REP          10000             .3                                                                                                                                          
Bernstein                 SA_REP           9500            .25                                                                                                                                          
Hall                      SA_REP           9000            .25                                                                                                                                          
Olsen                     SA_REP           8000             .2                                                                                                                                          
Cambrault                 SA_REP           7500             .2                                                                                                                                          
Tuvault                   SA_REP           7000            .15                                                                                                                                          
King                      SA_REP          10000            .35                                                                                                                                          
Sully                     SA_REP           9500            .35                                                                                                                                          
McEwen                    SA_REP           9000            .35                                                                                                                                          
Smith                     SA_REP           8000             .3                                                                                                                                          
Doran                     SA_REP           7500             .3                                                                                                                                          
Sewall                    SA_REP           7000            .25                                                                                                                                          
Vishney                   SA_REP          10500            .25                                                                                                                                          
Greene                    SA_REP           9500            .15                                                                                                                                          
Marvins                   SA_REP           7200             .1                                                                                                                                          
Lee                       SA_REP           6800             .1                                                                                                                                          
Ande                      SA_REP           6400             .1                                                                                                                                          
Banda                     SA_REP           6200             .1                                                                                                                                          
Ozer                      SA_REP          11500            .25                                                                                                                                          
Bloom                     SA_REP          10000             .2                                                                                                                                          
Fox                       SA_REP           9600             .2                                                                                                                                          
Smith                     SA_REP           7400            .15                                                                                                                                          
Bates                     SA_REP           7300            .15                                                                                                                                          
Kumar                     SA_REP           6100             .1                                                                                                                                          
Abel                      SA_REP          11000             .3                                                                                                                                          
Hutton                    SA_REP           8800            .25                                                                                                                                          
Taylor                    SA_REP           8600             .2                                                                                                                                          
Livingston                SA_REP           8400             .2                                                                                                                                          
Grant                     SA_REP           7000            .15                                                                                                                                          
Johnson                   SA_REP           6200             .1                                                                                                                                          
Taylor                    SH_CLERK         3200                                                                                                                                                         
Fleaur                    SH_CLERK         3100                                                                                                                                                         
Sullivan                  SH_CLERK         2500                                                                                                                                                         
Geoni                     SH_CLERK         2800                                                                                                                                                         
Sarchand                  SH_CLERK         4200                                                                                                                                                         
Bull                      SH_CLERK         4100                                                                                                                                                         
Dellinger                 SH_CLERK         3400                                                                                                                                                         
Cabrio                    SH_CLERK         3000                                                                                                                                                         
Chung                     SH_CLERK         3800                                                                                                                                                         
Dilly                     SH_CLERK         3600                                                                                                                                                         
Gates                     SH_CLERK         2900                                                                                                                                                         
Perkins                   SH_CLERK         2500                                                                                                                                                         
Bell                      SH_CLERK         4000                                                                                                                                                         
Everett                   SH_CLERK         3900                                                                                                                                                         
McCain                    SH_CLERK         3200                                                                                                                                                         
Jones                     SH_CLERK         2800                                                                                                                                                         
Walsh                     SH_CLERK         3100                                                                                                                                                         
Feeney                    SH_CLERK         3000                                                                                                                                                         
OConnell                  SH_CLERK         2600                                                                                                                                                         
Grant                     SH_CLERK         2600                                                                                                                                                         
Whalen                    AD_ASST          4400                                                                                                                                                         
Hartstein                 MK_MAN          13000                                                                                                                                                         
Fay                       MK_REP           6000                                                                                                                                                         
Mavris                    HR_REP           6500                                                                                                                                                         
Baer                      PR_REP          10000                                                                                                                                                         
Higgins                   AC_MGR          12008                                                                                                                                                         
Gietz                     AC_ACCOUNT       8300
```

And I tried the following query

```
SQL> select last_name, job_id, salary, commission_pct from employees where commission_pct=nvl(commission_pct,0);
```

It only shows employees that have a commission. But I want only those people that who have not commission.

Comment: LAST_NAME                 JOB_ID         SALARY COMMISSION_PCTRussell                   SA_MAN          14000             .4

Comment: oracle dbms for practising

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle function `NVL(expression, value)` converts any NULL values found in the `expression` to a `value` specified.

***Reference**: [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) (Oracle Documentation)*

Your statement actually checks each value of `commission_pct` and if it is `NULL` converts it to `0`.

You then compare the column `commission_pct` of every record returned which had a `NULL` value to the value `0`. This is never true.

### Example

```
Atkinson               ST_CLERK        2500     (NULL)
```

So running your statement:

```
select last_name, job_id, salary, commission_pct from employees where commission_pct=nvl(commission_pct,0);
```

....results in the case of Atkinson:

```
WHERE NULL = 0
```

### Explanation

The value of ATKINSON's `commision_pct` is `NULL`. When the record is retrieved by the database engine it checks the WHERE clause, and compares the left side of the expression (which is `NULL` for ATKINSON) and compares it with the converted value of `NULL` which is then `0`.

This is never true.

### Solution

```
SQL> SELECT last_name, job_id, salary, commission_pct from employees where commission_pct IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

```
SQL> select last_name, job_id, salary, commission_pct 
from employees 
where commission_pct IS NULL;
```

Or if the table definition for the column `commission_pct` is different you can try:

```
SQL> select last_name, job_id, salary, commission_pct 
from employees 
where commission_pct > 0 
and commission_pct < 0;
```

Comment: `where commission_pct > 0  and commission_pct < 0` is **never** true. How can a single value be greater then zero **and** smaller then zero?

Comment: my bad, equal signs are needed